# Select two elements from each category with SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Consider the following table

```
id | fruit | score
---+-------+------
1  | pear  | 9
2  | plum  | 5
3  | plum  | 7
4  | apple | 4
5  | plum  | 2
6  | pear  | 3
```

I need an SQL (POSTGRES dialect) query which selects the lowest scoring apples and plums, two from each category. The result would be

```
id | fruit | score
---+-------+------
 4 | apple | 4
 5 | plum  | 2
 2 | plum  | 5
```

I started with

```
SELECT id, fruit, score 
FROM fruit_score 
WHERE fruit IN ('apple', 'plum') 
ORDER BY score
```

How do I `LIMIT` by fruit?

Comment: . . Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` if you want to guarantee two rows per `fruit`:

```
select fs.*
from (select fs.*, row_number() over (partition by fruit order by score asc) as seqnum
      from fruit_score fs
      where fruit IN ('apple', 'plum') 
     ) fs
where seqnum <= 2;
```